# MS Dynamics CRM 2013 Installation issue

Tags: installation, microsoft-dynamics

While trying to install MS CRM on one of the VM, we are getting the error "Unable to browse for active directory objects" while "Select the Organization Unit" step. We discussed this with the client to give relevant permissions for Active Directory but client doesn't want to install CRM tied up with AD. Is there an option to install MS CRM with separate users rather than connecting with AD ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After detailed RnD and discussion with consultants, following are the options we have:

Option 1:

- Make a new domain in the AD
- Configure a new root OU
- Create a user having domain and AD admin rights

Option 2:

- Create a network admin user for both instances (db and app)
- Complete installation with an admin person at client who can use the
  admin user for CRM installation

The best case would be to get the Domain admin user but it's not that easy to get.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you would not be able to install CRM without using AD because of Microsoft's requirements to installation of CRM.